# Rotating a point around a center point, something wrong

Tags: rotation, point

in a current assignment we need to create a method, to rotate a given point, around
a center point given, in the angle given, in CLOCK WISED offset.
after searching through posts here, i thought i figured it out, but according to my 
teacher, something is wrong with this and i can't figure it out.

i was hoping maybe someone could help out pointing what the problem is.

this is my method

```
    /**
 * rotate this Point around a given enter point, with the given angle, in clock wised offset.
 * @param center - the center Point for rotation
 * @param angle - the size angle in degrees - to be rotate clock wised
 */
public void rotate(Point center, double angle){

    // convert the angle to radiant (to use with Math class methods). The negative sign is because, in trigonometry, default rotation is COUNTER-clock wised.
    double rad_angle = -Math.toRadians(angle); 

    // in order to rotate properly, we need to know the difference between the coordinates, to get a base for the rotation.
    double diff_x = this.x - center.X(); 
    double diff_y = this.y - center.Y(); 

    // calculate the rotation difference
    this.x = diff_x * Math.cos(rad_angle) - diff_y* Math.sin(rad_angle);  
    this.y = diff_x * Math.sin(rad_angle) + diff_y * Math.cos(rad_angle);

    // translate the differences back to this point
    this.x = this.x + center.X(); 
    this.y = this.y + center.Y();

    return;
}//rotate
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried passing it various test input values? What did you get, and what did you expect to get instead?

Comment: i think i've found what seems to be the problem -
as example , if i rotate < -5.0 , 2.5 > in 90 degrees,
instead of getting < 2.5 , 5.0 > i'm getting :
<2.4999999999999996,5.0>

i think its critical because in the assignment, this rotation must be precise.
if i use Math.round it will round it to 2.0, which is not good for me.

Comment: Doubles don't have exact values of 2.5. They are always approximations.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988821/comparison-of-float-and-double-variables

Comment: @Liron,
i don't understand. why does doubles don't have exact value of 2.5?
if i initialize
" double a = 100.0 / 40.0; "
for example, 'a' will be 2.5.
or did you mean something else and i'm missing the point?

Comment: @user3025555 Try it out. The way doubles (and all floating point numbers) work is that they are approximations of the real value. Try print out 10.0/4.0, 100.0/40.0, 1000.0/400.0 and see what you get.

Comment: The way to compare doubles for equality is to do `abs(double1 - double2) < 0.00001` or some other small value like that.

Comment: But either way, that's not your big problem. Have you tried it out with some known inputs and outputs to see what you get? Try with some simple things, like {-5,0} rotated around {0,0} by 90 degrees, should be {0,-5). Then try {-10,0} rotated around {-5,0} by 90 degrees should be {-5,-5}

Answer (score 0):

```
    angle += 0.2f * delta;
    position.x = target.x + (float) Math.sin(angle) * distanceFromCenter;
    position.y = target.y + (float) Math.cos(angle) * distanceFromCenter;
```

There's really nothing more to it.